# Identify IC component (voltage regulator?), L8=6G 93W

Tags: voltage-regulator, identification, short-circuit

I connected the PCB to the power supply to check which parts received power and which did not. In doing so I fear I may have short-circuited the 2 components, in fact they have now become hot when powered, furthermore several pins are short-circuited and grounded. I'm trying to identify them but I can't figure it out.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How hot? It can be normal for parts to be hot. How are you measuring the short? A large complex board may have a low resistance from power to ground.

Comment: Given the proximity of capacitors and large inductor, a PMIC is a decent guess.

Comment: one is hot enough to not allow you to hold your finger on it, I don't know in degrees but it really burns, the other has an acceptable temperature but I would still like to buy 1 to be safe. Comparing the 2 components which, although different, I believe have the same function in one if I measure the resistance between all the pins it is 0 while in the other it is not. Can any of you tell me what components they are exactly to check with the datasheet? I searched for the various acronyms but to no avail

Comment: Can you unsolder the IC and check if the short disappears?

Comment: Please edit the question to make it clear whether the device was working correctly before you started your measurements etc.

Comment: Those QFNs have huge solder balls. Was this reworked or hand soldered? Solder may have gotten under the IC if someone shoved an absurd amount of solder on the pads.

Comment: @Michael I think it's just a non-wettable-flank type, and the pads maybe should've been designed as LGA style rather than QFN.

Answer (score 5):

It's a [Richtek RT6256BGQUF](https://www.richtek.com/assets/product_file/RT6256B=RT6256C/DS6256BC-03.pdf) DC-DC step-down converter.

[image]